# Can't insert data to database | Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Error:**
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '', '0.02' , 'MINTME', '0x9cDc95C267BFa706aBF7f5c9C7340323d605bfA4', '2021-09-...' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\payoutRequest.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\payoutRequest.php(53): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\payoutRequest.php on line 53

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_id, user_id, amount, type, wallet_address, date, av_hashes, av_amount) VALUES('$generatePayoutID',$transaction_userid', '$inputAmounts' , '$inputCurrency', '$inputWallet', '$YMD', '$av_hashes', '$av_amount')";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([
':transaction_id' => $generatePayoutID,
':user_id' => $transaction_userid,
':amount' => $inputAmounts,
':type' => $inputCurrency,
':wallet_address' => $inputWallet,
':date' => $YMD,
':av_hashes' => $av_hashes,
':av_amount' => $av_amount
]);
```

```php
$sName = "localhost";
$uName = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "prunity_db";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$sName;dbname=$db_name", 
                    $uName, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it!

**Solution:**

```php
$insert_transaction = "INSERT INTO transactions(transaction_id, user_id, amount, type, wallet_address, date, av_hashes, av_amount)
VALUES(:transaction_id,:user_id,:amount,:type,:wallet_address,:date,:av_hashes,:av_amount)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($insert_transaction);
$statement->execute([
    ':transaction_id' => $generatePayoutID,
    ':user_id' => $transaction_userid,
    ':amount' => $inputAmounts,
    ':type' => $inputCurrency,
    ':wallet_address' => $inputWallet,
    ':date' => $YMD,
    ':av_hashes' => $av_hashes,
    ':av_amount' => $av_amount
]);
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this answer is the solution?

Comment: Looks like the tokens in the VALUES() statement were changed from `$blah` to `:blah`